# javascript on click button displays unnecessary `<div>`

Tags: javascript, html

Based on this http://qnimate.com/creating-a-wysiwyg-html-editor/ example created short code

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>WYSIWYG Editor</title>

 </head>
 <body>

 <button onclick="displayhtml()">Display HTML</button>
 <div class="editor" style="width: 50px; height: 100px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid grey;" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">
 </div>

 <div class="htmloutput">
 </div>

 <script>
 function displayhtml() {

 document.getElementsByClassName("htmloutput")[0].textContent = document.getElementsByClassName("editor")[0].innerHTML;
 }
 </script>    

 </body>

 </html>
```

On local computer created index file inside wamp/www and pasted the code.

Inside `class="editor"` typed Enter text Enter. Then clicked on `button onclick="displayhtml()"`

And i see 
`<div><br></div><div>text</div><div><br></div>`
instead of expected `<br>text<br>`

Tried here http://jsfiddle.net/24fyrhga/6/
All ok.

Why on local computer i see these `divs` and how to remove them?

Comment: Use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` when getting the value from textbox. Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/24fyrhga/7/)

Comment: @Tushar with `innerText` do not see `<br/>`. If i click Enter, want to see `<br/>` and do not want to see `div`